# Getting data about my channel (YouTube Data API v3 + Node.js)

Tags: node.js, youtube-data-api

According to YouTube Data API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true), I'm trying to get information about my channel.

I edited [this example](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs) and here how it looks now:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"];
const TOKEN_PATH = "token.json";

fs.readFile("credentials.json", (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listData);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function listData(auth) {
  const service = google.youtube({ version: "v3" });
  service.search.list(
    {
      key: <key>,
      auth,
      maxResults: 1,
      part: "snippet",
      mine: true,
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.error("The API returned an error: " + err);
      fs.writeFileSync("current.json", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  );
}
```

It doesn't get data about my channel.

Here is a valid data about my channel (according to documentation):

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "HOiFDW01gFa3OOv6jTbsDBNWk5s",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "W8UW4c6qU25jUIwK7dbUKZ6myVs",
      "id": "UCdsDGgbcWylt82Xz238WKDw",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Anton Kryukov",
        "description": "",
        "publishedAt": "2013-12-29T20:20:32Z",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": { Object },
          "medium": { Object },
          "high": { Object }
        },
        "localized": {
          "title": "Anton Kryukov",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is data which I got:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "thdFV9K466l_42uNDJ-UzfurpAM",
  "regionCode": "UA",
  "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 1000000, "resultsPerPage": 1 },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "TDM6iLWG7SU62NtW2bhkoVu9slw",
      "id": { "kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "0NhViwSjLdk" },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-02-07T05:57:26Z",
        "channelId": "UCqFzWxSCi39LnW1JKFR3efg",
        "title": "Universal Tram - SNL",
        "description": "A tour guide (Mikey Day) has a hard time controlling his jittery trainee (Dan Levy). Saturday Night Live. Stream now on Peacock: ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": { Object },
          "medium": { Object },
          "high": { Object }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Saturday Night Live",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-02-07T05:57:26Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to acknowledge that by this code of yours:

```js
service.search.list(
    {
      auth,
      maxResults: 1,
      part: "snippet",
      mine: true,
    }
    ...
);
```

you're not invoking the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, but the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) one.

Please take note to the fact that `Search.list` has no [request parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) named `mine`.

Instead of the code above, you'll have to have something like the one below:

```js
service.channels.list(
    {
      auth: auth,
      maxResults: 1,
      part: "snippet",
      mine: true,
    }
    ...
);
```

See the YouTube Data API's official document [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs) for the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample) therein to convince yourself even more about the fix above.